# Pandas weird one to many join

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose you have two pandas data frames df1 with column A1 and df2 with columns B2, C3 and D3.

Column A1 maps to B2 C3, D3 sometimes. Write a custom function that uses df1 and df2 to add a column that refers to the values you used to join.

ex:

```
df1   |df2
'A1'  | 'B2' 'C3' 'D3'
      |
 1    |  6     1   10
 2    |  7     4    2
 3    |  3     9    11
```

the resulting dataframe df3 should look this.

```
function: df3= mutiple_joins(df1,df2,lefton=['A1'],right_one=['B2','C3,'D3'],join_id='#12')
df3
'A1' 'B2' 'C3' 'D3' 'join_id: #12'
 1    6   1     10   1
 2    7   4     2    2
 3    3   9     11   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, an approach with multiple `merge` and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
def multiple_joins(df1, df2, left_on, right_on, join_id):
    left = df1.reset_index()
    return (pd.concat([left.merge(df2, left_on=L, right_on=R)
                           .assign(**{f'join_id: {join_id}': lambda d: d[L]})
                       for L in left_on
                       for R in right_on
                      ])
              .set_index(df1.index.name or 'index')
              .sort_index().rename_axis(df1.index.name)
           )

out = multiple_joins(df1, df2, left_on=['A1'], right_on=['B2','C3','D3'], join_id='#12')
```

Output:

```
   A1  B2  C3  D3  join_id: #12
0   1   6   1  10             1
1   2   7   4   2             2
2   3   3   9  11             3
```

A more complex example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1, 2, 3], 'A2': [0, 9, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B2': [6, 7, 3], 'C3': [1, 4, 9], 'D3': [10, 2, 11]})

out = multiple_joins(df1, df2, left_on=['A1', 'A2'], right_on=['B2','C3','D3'],
                     join_id='#12')

   A1  A2  B2  C3  D3  join_id: #12
0   1   0   6   1  10             1
1   2   9   7   4   2             2
1   2   9   3   9  11             9
2   3   1   3   9  11             3
2   3   1   6   1  10             1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using pandas' merge function to perform multiple joins. Below is the custom function multiple_joins:

```
import pandas as pd

def multiple_joins(df1, df2, left_on, right_on, join_id):
    # Perform the first join
    merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=left_on[0], right_on=right_on[0], suffixes=('', '_x'))
    
    # Loop through additional join conditions
    for i in range(1, len(left_on)):
        merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df, df2, left_on=left_on[i], right_on=right_on[i], suffixes=('', f'_{i+1}'))
    
    # Add join_id column
    merged_df['join_id'] = join_id
    
    # Drop duplicate columns
    for i in range(len(right_on)):
        merged_df.drop(right_on[i], axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    return merged_df

# Example usage
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B2': [6, 7, 3], 'C3': [1, 4, 9], 'D3': [10, 2, 11]})

df3 = multiple_joins(df1, df2, left_on=['A1'], right_on=['B2', 'C3', 'D3'], join_id='#12')
print(df3)
```

This function takes two dataframes df1 and df2, along with the columns to join on (left_on and right_on), and a join_id to identify the join. It returns the resulting dataframe df3 with the desired columns.